# How to handle optional belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, null-object-pattern

USECASE:

Consider the following example.

```
Class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 attr_accessible :title
end
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :foo
 attr_accessible :name
end
```

If a logged-in user creates Foo, it will be associated to its user record. If a not logged-in user creates Foo, it wont be associated to any user. This is just an example and I have a lot of similar use cases in my application.

PROBLEM:

The problem is my view code gets cluttered with a lot of if conditions and ternary operations like,

```
<% foo.user ? foo.user.name : "not set"%>
```

CURRENT SOLUTION:

To overcome this, I am using the null object design pattern. The User class defines a NullUser object (whose name will be set to "not set"). If a foo object does not have user object, it will return a NullUser object. I have overridden the user method in Foo class which does the nil check.

QUESTION:

1. Is there a better solution to this?
2. Is there a gem which facilitates
   the null object pattern for rails active record models.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the perfect case for a decorator that wraps your user object. All the logic about what to display goes in there; all your view cares about is that it can spit out the object's name.

[Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) works well for decorators in Rails.

And a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper) for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution would be to set a default value and associate it with a guest user.  That way it would be overridden when a user was present, but would mean there would always be a value when you call .user.name